# Want to add extra key in mongoose records while making json in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    actions:[{actionid:String, actiondata:String}],
    author: String  
})
```

While fetching the records, i need count for `action = 1`. And i want to add the count as a extra key in each comment as below:

```
{
"comments":[
          {"commentData":{
              "text":"temp1",
              "author":"tempauthor1",
              "actioncount":"2"
           }},
          {"commentData":{
              "text":"temp1",
              "author":"tempauthor2",
              "actioncount":"3"
           }}
]}
```

I need json response like this. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean `count for 'action = 1'`? the length of actions is `1`?

Comment: It's really confusing what are you trying to ask... where is the field `likecount` in your schema? and also `author` and `tempauthor` in your schema. Please make the question more clear

Comment: Actionid will be 3 different types. For instance, 1 comment have 10 actions, 2 actions will be having actionid=1, 5 actions will have actionid=2 and 3 actions will have action=3. My filter will be like, i need only actionid = 1 and the count of actionid=1. I want to add action count for each commentdata which is not in the schema.

Answer (score 4):

To filter only `actionid = 1` and the count of `actionid=1`. Please try to do it through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

```
Comment.aggregate([{$unwind: '$actions'},
                   // filter the actionid is 1
                   {$match: {'actions.actionid': '1'}},
                   // 
                   {$group: {_id: 'actions.actionid',
                             actioncount: {$sum: 1}
                             }}
   ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code you gave is returning the total actions count for all the comments. But i need individual actions count for each comment and i want to add the count to each comment in the json response.

Comment: @Hari, Wow, if I catch you correctly, please try this one `{$group: {_id: {id: '$_id', actionId: '$actions.actionid'},
                             actioncount: {$sum: 1}
                             }}` or `{$group: {_id: '$_id',actioncount: {$sum: 1}}}`

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks alot. Finally i am getting the count for individual action count for each comment. I am able to get the json response as [ { _id: 56cf31d06ad801ef10e9a, actioncount: 2 },
  { _id: 56cf31ed873801ef10e9c, actioncount: 1 },
  { _id: 56cf31bd6a3801ef10e98, actioncount: 2 },
  { _id: 56cf2a29d67751c29f51c, actioncount: 5 } ]. Can i add the remaining attributes "text" and "author" to the json response?

Comment: @Hari, to remaining the `text` and `author`, try `{$group: {_id: '$_id', authors: {$push: '$author'}, texts: {$push: '$text'}, actioncount: {$sum: 1}}}`

Comment: Actually your code is giving double and triple of the values. I tried this code {$group: {_id:{title: '$title',media: '$media'},actioncount: {$sum: 0}}}. This works fine. Thanks. This command is returning the comments which is having minimum 1 action but not 0 actions.